# "Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed" on wordpress when update/install plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My friend uses app engine, cloud storage and SQL to install wordpress on google cloud platform. But after that he gets a notification when installing / updating plugins and themes like my screenshot in below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqU8Y.png

What I've done:

1. Change wordpress folder permissions via cloud shell with CHMOD 755
2. Added code `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` in wp-config.php via cloud shell
   However, I still can't update/install plugins and themes.
   Maybe there's a way I can use to fix it?

**UPDATE 1 :**

Here's my result when i check with command `lsb_release -a`
No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Debian

Description: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Release: 11

Answer (score 0):

This problem is often caused by incorrect file township of the site’s WordPress files. When you extract the WordPress files from a tar achieve, the resulting files are owned by the user **nobody** and the group **nogroup**. WordPress is running under the user **www-data** and the group **www-data**.

**Solution**

Go to the root of the Apache site. For example, **/var/www/mysite.com**. Execute `ls -l` and verify the file ownership. Change the file owner and group to **www-data**.

```
ls -l
total 216
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup   405 Feb  6  2020 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup 19915 Jan  1  2021 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup  7346 Jul  6 12:23 readme.html
[extra content removed]
```

To change the file ownership, execute the following command either as root or with sudo:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

The -R option means to perform the command recursively. All files in the current directory and all subdirectories will be affected. Consult the Linux man page for more information.

[chown(1) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html)

Comment: I just changed the owner of my website folder to www-data. But it has no effect on my website. And actually, i didnt find the var/www directory.

Comment: @AdityaIrvandani - What is the OS and which web server? Knowing that will tell you what the directory is. /var/www/ is the default for Ubuntu + Apache.

Comment: How do I check the OS and web server I'm using? I searched the internet only to find for virtual machines.

Comment: @AdityaIrvandani - Use the command **lsb_release -a**.

Comment: here is the result :
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11